# Event ($watch) after input field (ng-modal) has been completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, watch

I have a text input field that asks for a name:

```
<input type="text" ng-modal="form.name" placeholder="Enter NAME">
```

and I have a watch funcition listening to form.name

```
scope.$watch('form.name', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    //TODO: foo()
});
```

foo is being called every time a letter appears, but I want to be able to only call foo when the input field has been completed(either by deselecting input field or another trigger).

foo() is an expensive call that I want to do only when the input field has been done.

NOTE: there will be multiple input-fields following this process, so I don't want a button for each or do them all at once.

Comment: use [`ng-blur`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur)

Comment: oooohhhhh, I completely forgot about ng-blur, Thank you :). However I am still curious about other solution, specially if the modal is being passed down to another directive :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) available in angular 1.3:

```
<input type="text" ng-modal="form.name" placeholder="Enter NAME"          
 ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': 500, 'blur': 0} }">
```

now your model gets updated only after the input loses his focus or the user stops typing for 500ms.

Comment: `debounce` is built in, that's awesome! I haven't seen it anywhere other than Underscore/Lodash.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you look at **Lodash**/**UnderscoreJS** for help with this sort of thing.

These libraries provide awesome helper methods for working with collections, objects and (most importantly to you) functions.

The method that will solve your problem is [`_.debounce(func, [wait=0], [options])`](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce).

The basic gist of `_.debounce` is to prevent calls happening in a rapid succession. If the method hasn't been called in a certain amount of time, then the method will actually execute.

Example:

```
foo = _.debounce(foo, 200); // foo will now only execute 
                            //  after it has not been called for 200ms.

scope.$watch('form.name', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    foo(); // Expensive call that updates something...
});
```

In this example, I can call `foo` as many times as I want, but it won't be until `200ms` after I call it that it will execute. This is perfect for auto-complete style boxes, which seems similar to what you are working on. It's also really great for window resize, animated navigation, and custom markdown editors.

Comment: Lets say I type 5 letters in a sec, are all 5 calls going to wait for 200ms, and will they be async?

Comment: Let's say you type 5 letters in 100ms. Since we specified a 200ms delay, it will only execute once, 200ms after the last key was pressed. On the other hand, if you type 1 key every 1000ms then it will execute every time, because there was at least 200ms between each call.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad @MajoB had the easy answer!